# I can't use ngMaterial

Tags: angularjs

When i use use ngMaterial i have this error

```
Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.7/$injector/modulerr?p0=admin&p1=%5B%24injector%3Amodulerr%5D%20http%3A%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.4.7%2F%24injector%2Fmodulerr%3Fp0%3DngMaterial%26p1%3D%255B%2524injector%253Amodulerr%255D%2520http%253A%252F%252Ferrors.angularjs.org%252F1.4.7%252F%2524injector%252Fmodulerr%253Fp0%253DngAnimate%2526p1%253D%25255B%252524injector%25253Anomod%25255D%252520http%25253A%25252F%25252Ferrors.angularjs.org%25252F1.4.7%25252F%252524injector%25252Fnomod%25253Fp0%25253DngAnimate%25250AI%25252F%25253C%252540http%25253A%25252F%25252Fajax.googleapis.com%25252Fajax%25252Flibs%25252Fangularjs%25252F1.4.7%25252Fangular.min.js%25253A6%25253A416%25250Ade%25252F%25253C%25252F%25253C%25252F%25253C%252540http%25253A%25252F%25252Fajax.googleapis.com%25252Fajax%25252Flibs%25252Fangularjs%25252F1.4.7%25252Fangular.min.js%25253A24%25253A186%25250Aa%252540http%25253A%25252F%25252Fajax.googleapis.com%25252Fajax%25252Flibs%25252Fangularjs%25252F1.4.7%25252Fangular.min.js%25253A23%25253A252%25250Ade%25252F%25253C%25252F%25253C%252540http%25253A%25252F%25252Fajax.googleapis.com%25252Fajax%25252Flibs%25252Fangularjs%25252F1.4.7%25252Fangular.min.js%25253A23%25253A495%25250Ah%25252F%25253C%252540http%25253A%25252F%25252Fajax.googleapis.com%25252Fajax%25252Flibs%25252Fangularjs%25252F1.4.7%25252Fangular.min.js%25253A37%25253A427%25250Am%252540http%25253A%25252F%25252Fajax.googleapis.com%25252Fajax%25252Flibs%25252Fangularjs%25252F1.4.7%25252Fangular.min.js%25253A7%25253A320%25250Ah%252540http%25253A%25252F%25252Fajax.googleapis.com%25252Fajax%25252Flibs%25252Fangularjs%25252F1.4.7%25252Fangular.min.js%25253A37%25253A275%25250Ah%25252F%25253C%252540http%25253A%25252F%25252Fajax.googleapis.com%25252Fajax%25252Flibs%25252Fangularjs%25252F1.4.7%25252Fangular.min.js%25253A37%25253A444%25250Am%252540http%25253A%25252F%25252Fajax.googleapis.com%25252Fajax%25252Flibs%25252Fangularjs%25252F1.4.7%25252Fangular.min.js%25253A7%25253A320%25250Ah%252540http%25253A%25252F%25252Fajax.googleapis.com%25252Fajax%25252Flibs%25252Fangularjs%25252F1.4.7%25252Fangular.min.js%25253A37%25253A275%25250Ah%25252F%25253C%252540http%25253A%25252F%25252Fajax.googleapis.com%25252Fajax%25252Flibs%25252Fangularjs%25252F1.4.7%25252Fangular.min.js%25253A37%25253A444%25250Am%252540http%25253A%25252F%25252Fajax.googleapis.com%25252Fajax%25252Flibs%25252Fangularjs%25252F1.4.7%25252Fangular.min.js%25253A7%25253A320%25250Ah%252540http%25253A%25252F%25252Fajax.googleapis.com%25252Fajax%25252Flibs%25252Fangularjs%25252F1.4.7%25252Fangular.min.js%25253A37%25253A275%25250Afb%252540http%25253A%25252F%25252Fajax.googleapis.com%25252Fajax%25252Flibs%25252Fangularjs%25252F1.4.7%25252Fangular.min.js%25253A41%25253A35%25250Azc%25252Fd%252540http%25253A%25252F%25252Fajax.googleapis.com%25252Fajax%25252Flibs%25252Fangularjs%25252F1.4.7%25252Fangular.min.js%25253A19%25253A463%25250Azc%252540http%25253A%25252F%25252Fajax.googleapis.com%25252Fajax%25252Flibs%25252Fangularjs%25252F1.4.7%25252Fangular.min.js%25253A20%25253A274%25250A%252540http%25253A%25252F%25252Flocalhost%25253A3000%25252Fadmin%25252Fadmin.js%25253A53%25253A13%25250Am.Callbacks%25252Fj%252540http%25253A%25252F%25252Flocalhost%25253A3000%25252Fadmin%25252Fadmin-content%25252Fjs%25252Fjquery.js%25253A2%25253A27239%25250Am.Callbacks%25252Fk.fireWith%252540http%25253A%25252F%25252Flocalhost%25253A3000%25252Fadmin%25252Fadmin-content%25252Fjs%25252Fjquery.js%25253A2%25253A28057%25250Ax%252540http%25253A%25252F%25252Flocalhost%25253A3000%25252Fadmin%25252Fadmin-content%25252Fjs%25252Fjquery.js%25253A4%25253A21841%25250A.send%25252Fb%252540http%25253A%25252F%25252Flocalhost%25253A3000%25252Fadmin%25252Fadmin-content%25252Fjs%25252Fjquery.js%25253A4%25253A25897%25250A%250AI%252F%253C%2540http%253A%252F%252Fajax.googleapis.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangularjs%252F1.4.7%252Fangular.min.js%253A6%253A416%250Ah%252F%253C%2540http%253A%252F%252Fajax.googleapis.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangularjs%252F1.4.7%252Fangular.min.js%253A38%253A184%250Am%2540http%253A%252F%252Fajax.googleapis.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangularjs%252F1.4.7%252Fangular.min.js%253A7%253A320%250Ah%2540http%253A%252F%252Fajax.googleapis.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangularjs%252F1.4.7%252Fangular.min.js%253A37%253A275%250Ah%252F%253C%2540http%253A%252F%252Fajax.googleapis.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangularjs%252F1.4.7%252Fangular.min.js%253A37%253A444%250Am%2540http%253A%252F%252Fajax.googleapis.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangularjs%252F1.4.7%252Fangular.min.js%253A7%253A320%250Ah%2540http%253A%252F%252Fajax.googleapis.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangularjs%252F1.4.7%252Fangular.min.js%253A37%253A275%250Ah%252F%253C%2540http%253A%252F%252Fajax.googleapis.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangularjs%252F1.4.7%252Fangular.min.js%253A37%253A444%250Am%2540http%253A%252F%252Fajax.googleapis.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangularjs%252F1.4.7%252Fangular.min.js%253A7%253A320%250Ah%2540http%253A%252F%252Fajax.googleapis.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangularjs%252F1.4.7%252Fangular.min.js%253A37%253A275%250Afb%2540http%253A%252F%252Fajax.googleapis.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangularjs%252F1.4.7%252Fangular.min.js%253A41%253A35%250Azc%252Fd%2540http%253A%252F%252Fajax.googleapis.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangularjs%252F1.4.7%252Fangular.min.js%253A19%253A463%250Azc%2540http%253A%252F%252Fajax.googleapis.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangularjs%252F1.4.7%252Fangular.min.js%253A20%253A274%250A%2540http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A3000%252Fadmin%252Fadmin.js%253A53%253A13%250Am.Callbacks%252Fj%2540http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A3000%252Fadmin%252Fadmin-content%252Fjs%252Fjquery.js%253A2%253A27239%250Am.Callbacks%252Fk.fireWith%2540http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A3000%252Fadmin%252Fadmin-content%252Fjs%252Fjquery.js%253A2%253A28057%250Ax%2540http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A3000%252Fadmin%252Fadmin-content%252Fjs%252Fjquery.js%253A4%253A21841%250A.send%252Fb%2540http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A3000%252Fadmin%252Fadmin-content%252Fjs%252Fjquery.js%253A4%253A25897%250A%0AI%2F%3C%40http%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.4.7%2Fangular.min.js%3A6%3A416%0Ah%2F%3C%40http%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.4.7%2Fangular.min.js%3A38%3A184%0Am%40http%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.4.7%2Fangular.min.js%3A7%3A320%0Ah%40http%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.4.7%2Fangular.min.js%3A37%3A275%0Ah%2F%3C%40http%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.4.7%2Fangular.min.js%3A37%3A444%0Am%40http%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.4.7%2Fangular.min.js%3A7%3A320%0Ah%40http%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.4.7%2Fangular.min.js%3A37%3A275%0Afb%40http%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.4.7%2Fangular.min.js%3A41%3A35%0Azc%2Fd%40http%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.4.7%2Fangular.min.js%3A19%3A463%0Azc%40http%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.4.7%2Fangular.min.js%3A20%3A274%0A%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fadmin%2Fadmin.js%3A53%3A13%0Am.Callbacks%2Fj%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fadmin%2Fadmin-content%2Fjs%2Fjquery.js%3A2%3A27239%0Am.Callbacks%2Fk.fireWith%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fadmin%2Fadmin-content%2Fjs%2Fjquery.js%3A2%3A28057%0Ax%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fadmin%2Fadmin-content%2Fjs%2Fjquery.js%3A4%3A21841%0A.send%2Fb%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fadmin%2Fadmin-content%2Fjs%2Fjquery.js%3A4%3A25897%0A
```

angular.min.js:6:416

Answer (score 1):

If you follow that link Angular provide some details as to what might be the reason.

Here is a snippet:

```
Description
This error occurs when a module fails to load due to some exception. The error message above should provide additional context.

A common reason why the module fails to load is that you've forgotten to include the file with the defined module or that the file couldn't be loaded.
```

So it looks like you have not included the ngMaterial module.